# Find all documents that have two specific id's in an array of objects. MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Hello I've got a mongodb find() question query. I am trying to find all documents that have two specific id's in the same array of objects.

Sample Document Structure:

doc 1

```
{
    gameId:394028,
    people: [{
      id: 5,
      mapSide: 'left'
   },{
      id: 4,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 1,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 2,
      mapSide: 'left'
   }]
}
```

doc 2

```
{
    gameId:394028,
    people: [{
      id: 7,
      mapSide: 'left'
   },{
      id: 9,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 4,
      mapSide: 'right'
   },{
      id: 1,
      mapSide: 'left'
   }]
}
```

How would I go about getting all documents that have an id of 5 and 4 in the same people array?
I've tried this shell command:

```
    db.COLLECTION.find({"people.id":5, "people.id":4}); //should return doc 1
```

However I am yet to get any results. I also intend to find the id only if they have a different map side - I've tried this:

```
    db.COLLECTION.find({
         people: {$elemMatch:{id:4, mapSide:"left"}, 
         people: {$elemMatch:{id:1, mapSide:"right"}
    },{
         people: {$elemMatch:{id:4, mapSide:"right"}, 
         people: {$elemMatch:{id:1, mapSide:"left"}
    }); //Should return doc 2, because doc 1 has both mapSide as 'right'
```

If I could have a hand for either of those questions, that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: For your first question: `db.COLLECTION.find( { $and : [ { 'people.id' : 4 }, { 'people.id' : 5 } ] } )`.

Comment: @go-oleg Thanks, I'll try that out, that should help me fix my other question as well.

Comment: @go-oleg By the way, your code helped me solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following query to find all documents where the `people` array contains both an element with `id == 4` and an element with `id == 5`:

```
db.COLLECTION.find( { $and : [ { 'people.id' : 4 }, { 'people.id' : 5 } ] } )
```